# Python Click: How to implement a help command that behaves like `--help`?

Tags: python, python-click

I have a python click CLI. When I pass `--help` to any command it prints a help message which I love. I've found that many users these days are typing

```
mycli help foo
```

instead of

```
mycli foo --help
```

Is there a way to make the former work just like the latter in a generic manner for all commands?

The command is implemented roughly like so

```
@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    ctx.obj = {}

@cli.command()
@click.argument('my_arg')
@click.pass_context
@report_errors
def foo(ctx, my_arg):
    # some stuff here
```

Comment: This would be more answerable if you were to give an example showing how you are building your commands.  There are multiple ways to build the above and they will have slightly different solutions.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch! I updated the question.

Comment: I should add, that I'm looking for a general purpose sort of solution. My actual CLI has lots of commands and I want the `help` command to work for all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`click.Command` objects have a [`get_help()`](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.Command.get_help) method that returns their `--help` string.  Combining this with the group's [`get_command()`](http://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.Group.get_command) method for looking up subcommands, something like this should work (untested):

```
@cli.command()
@click.argument('subcommand')
@click.pass_context
def help(ctx, subcommand):
    subcommand_obj = cli.get_command(ctx, subcommand)
    if subcommand_obj is None:
        click.echo("I don't know that command.")
    else:
        click.echo(subcommand_obj.get_help(ctx))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works 99% of the way, but the usage string has `help` as the subcommand instead of `subcommand`. Do you know of a fix around that?

Comment: @JesseShieh: No, I don't.

Comment: I added a line above that says `ctx.info_name = subcommand` which seems to work.